# XML serializing and encoding="utf-16"

Tags: c#, serialization, encoding, xml-serialization

I am serializing my object **DataCheck** using Stringwriter  and writing the text in the variable strData.  Finally the value of strdata  goes to the database.

```
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataCheck));
    serializer.Serialize(writer, objData);
    string strData =  writer.ToString();
```

If I check the contents of variable strdata it comes with default encoding (encoding="utf-16")

String strData value is below

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
       <DataCheck xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <JobList>
    <Job>
      <JobId>500</JobId>
      <JobDate>1/1/2013</JobDate>
      <Jobdesc>Test the app </Jobdesc>
    </Job>
 </JobList>
</DataCheck>
```

Q . I need to remove this encoding so that my XML content should look like without encoding
    how to do that and what I am missing.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
       <DataCheck xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                                             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <JobList>
    <Job>
      <JobId>500</JobId>
      <JobDate>1/1/2013</JobDate>
      <Jobdesc>Test the app </Jobdesc>
    </Job>
 </JobList>
</DataCheck>
```

Comment: _"I need to remove this encoding..."_ Why?

Comment: Try this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025365/serialize-and-deserialize-xml-using-dot-net-c-sharp

Comment: I need to remove the encoding for deserializing the XML back into object.